# find similar data in database django

Tags: python, django, database, similarity

for my university project, I'm developing a website that you search for a book and it shows you similar books to that. I'm using Django and I need help for finding the similars especially in fields that are strings.

```
from django.db import models

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    titleid = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    title= models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)


    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Film."""
        return self.primarytitle
```

I just want to add 100 books in total for my project but if I could develop it in a way that in future I'd be able to add 1000 books and still the speed would be the same would be perfect.
for rating, it's a number of rating(from 0 to 5) * number of people who vote for it. I'm getting this data from Goodreads. for example if a book has a score of 5 and 10 people vote is NOT similar to a book who has a score of 5 with 1 million votes. the rating for the first one would be 50 and the second one would be 5 million. from other posts, I've learned that for integers I can get the absolute value of the difference from their ratings and sort it in that way. so a book with 4.5 and 1 million votes would be more similar to the mentioned book than a book with a score of 5 but 500000 votes because the rating would be 4.5 million and 2.5 million respectively.

But I don't want the rating to be the only thing to consider. I want to consider the genre as well. for example, a book that has 5 million rating and genre of horror, fantasy would be more similar to a book with 4.5 million rating genre horror, fantasy, coming to age than a book with 5 million rating but the genre of an adult, romance.

how can I create something that finds this kind of similarity? if I can do it for genre then later I can add other features like Author as well. but I have no idea how to find the similarity based on the genre which is a String.

for the absolute value i've written this :

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
source = csv.DictReader(open('sample.tsv','r',encoding='utf-8'),delimiter ='\t')
bookdict= {}

for row in source:
    totalscore = float(row['avgRating'])* int(row['numVotes'])
    bookdict[row['bookid']] = int(totalscore)

absdict ={}

for key in bookdict:
    diff =int(abs(#specific book rate#- bookdict[key]))
    absdict[key] = diff

simlarbooks = OrderedDict(sorted(absdict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

for book in simlarbooks :
    print(book ,simlarbooks[book])
```

I'd be really grateful if you could advise me for the genre and other string parts.

Comment: May be it is better to look at search engines? Like Haystack+Whoosh (for beginning, also far more complicated - Solr and ElasticSearch).

Comment: @Chiefir thank you very much. I've checked their website. as far as i understood, they search those data based on the similarity of the text. and as they mentioned i should turn the related objects like many to many relationships to strings. so a book with genre of Fantasy,Horror becomes a string of 'Fantasy,Horror' and based on what i understood 'fantasy,horror' is not a 100 percent match with 'Horror,fantasy' which is wrong. it is. this is the problem i had with difflib as well. for 'Horror,fantasy' and 'Fantasy,Horror' it doesn't give me 100 percent match. how should i solve that??

Comment: 1) May be try to force converting `.lower()`? 2) I have used H+W and find out its `more_like_that` giving excellently matching results, so may be test it?

Comment: Also search in my profile my question about comparing strings similarity (I am from smartphone now and can find a link through the app) - may be that will help you somehow too.

Comment: And also with second case - if you have short strings - may be try to split them and next use `itertools.permutations` (if I remember correctly) to check if any combination matches given query.

Comment: @Chiefir Thank you very much. More_like_this function is working with models which is i guess much better for my case. so i wouldn't have to turn them to string and apply different algorithms. I've just read the documentation but i haven't tried it yet. I'm going to try it asap and see if i get what i want. I've also found the question you mentioned i've tested the solution it worked for your example really good but as soon as i change the place of SOME and TEXT so it be TEXT and SOME it won't work properly. Thank you very much for your help. I hope more_like_this works :)